# How to get the attribute from an object HTMLTableCellElement?

Tags: javascript

I need to get the COLSPAN attribute of my TD, but when I try to print the TD value the results is object HTMLTableCellElement.
Below you can find the HTML code and the routine to print the TD value. I want to print the value of the TD and the COLSPAN value. Thanks for your help

```
<TD CLASS=HD1 COLSPAN=2>TOP PAGE FAULT RATE</TD>
<TD CLASS=HD1 COLSPAN=2>TOP PAGE OUT RATE</TD>




  function getColumnsVal(id) {

    var header = $("table#" + id + " thead tr:eq(1)");
    var header_fields = $("td", header);

    for (index = 0; index < header_fields.length; ++index) {
    var MyCol = header_fields [index];
    alert(MyCol);       
    }
```

Comment: Try with ```MyCol.attr('COLSPAN');```

Comment: Hi Oscar, thanks. But innerHTML gives me just the content of the TD. Do yo know I can i get also the value of the COLSPAN attribute? thankss

Comment: MyCol.attr('COLSPAN'); doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var td= document.getElementsByTagName('TD');
var colspan = td[0].getAttribute('COLSPAN');

alert(colspan)
```

Comment: Ciao Paolo. I cannot use var td= document.getElementsByTagName('TD'); because in this way I get all the TD of all my HTML tables, so I cannot use document.getElementsByTagName

Comment: Can you give an id to the TD you want to get the colspan attribute?

Comment: Nope but I have the cass HD1 for this TD. The poiint is that in the same page I have different tables so I need to take only the TD of the table I select

Comment: You should set a specific class when a table is selected and then work on this. It's only a suggestion, I think you need to do some attemps

Comment: I cannot do this.. I will try to get the colspan  :(

Comment: You have to differentiate the TD you want to get the colspan attribute in some way to do this

Comment: Ok I tried and with getAttribute it worked! Thanks. Now I have both the values:

Comment: var MyCol = Firstheader_fields[index].innerHTML;
  var MyColspan = Firstheader_fields[index].getAttribute('COLSPAN');